# Zoomable image on Lightning Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, community, images

I need to implement dynamic zoom or a "Magnifying Glass" on an image on Lightning Component(Community).
Example: https://sularome.github.io/Zoomple/

I have searched many sites and tried to implement it with Zoomple plugin for JQuery but it doesn't work for some reason.

Is there any way to do this?
Do you know some JS libraries or something that can help me with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zoomple can be integrated as other JS libraries. There is some issue in image referencing in libraries otherwise it is working as expected.

**Steps to integrate:**

- Add all js file and images as zip in **static resource**.
- Create lighting component using this static resource

**Code:**
**ZoomComponent.cmp**

```
<aura:component >
      <ltng:require 
     styles="{!join(',', 
        $Resource.zoomple + '/styles.css', 
        $Resource.zoomple + '/zoomple.css')}"
       scripts="{!join(',', 
        $Resource.zoomple + '/jquery-3.3.1.min.js', $Resource.zoomple + '/jquery-migrate-1.4.1.min.js', 
        $Resource.zoomple + '/zoomple.js')}"
    afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.scriptsLoaded}" />
    <div id="wrapper">

    <div class="section section5">
        <h2>Sniper zoom (with cross) </h2> 
        <div class="section">
        <h2>Default settings</h2>
        <a href="{!$Resource.zoomple + '/DSC_8488.jpg'}" class="zoomple"><img src="{!$Resource.zoomple + '/DSC_8488.jpg'}" alt="" style="height:100px;width;100px" /> </a>
        </div>

        <a href="{!$Resource.zoomple + '/DSC_8488.jpg'}" class="zoomplecross"><img src="{!$Resource.zoomple + '/DSC_8488.jpg'}" style="height:100px;width;100px" /></a>
    </div>
</div>
</aura:component>
```

**ZoomComponent.js controller**

```
({
    scriptsLoaded : function(component, event, helper) {
        var blank = window.location.protocol +'//'+ window.location.host + $A.get('$Resource.zoomple') + '/blank.gif';
        var loader = window.location.protocol +'//'+ window.location.host + $A.get('$Resource.zoomple') + '/loader.gif';
        var cursor = window.location.protocol +'//'+ window.location.host + $A.get('$Resource.zoomple') + '/cursor.png';
        $(document).ready(function() {  

            var url={ 
                bgColor : '#90D5D9',
                offset : {x:-150,y:-150},
                zoomWidth : 300,  
                zoomHeight : 300,
                roundedCorners : true
            };
            url.blankURL=blank;
            url.loaderURL=loader;
            url.cursorURL=cursor;
            $('.zoomple').zoomple(url);

             var url1={ 
                bgColor : '#90D5D9',
                offset : {x:-10,y:-10},
                zoomWidth : 300,  
                zoomHeight : 300,
                roundedCorners : true
            };
            url1.blankURL=blank;
            url1.loaderURL=loader;
            url1.cursorURL=cursor;
            $('.zoomplecross').zoomple(url1); 
         }); 
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks. In fact, it is all good with libraries, but it starts working only when I put code into a console in developer tools of browser. Also, I have tried your variant and some error throws up: "Uncaught ReferenceError: thumbPosition is not defined
throws at https://surewerx--qa.lightning.force.com/resource/1562150272000/Zoomple/Zoomple-master/zoomple.js:197:18"

Comment: Please use files from github.com/dhaniksahni/Zommable. I have changed js files to resolve issue

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works!